# Unable to query Active Directory,remote procedure call failed intermediate failure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

in .Net 4.5 MVC web application we are using AD based roles, for this we are relying on 
         `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name)`

But looking at the elmah logs we found this to be failing unexpectedly for some of the requests not all

inner Stack Trace

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: Unable to query Active Directory. ---> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryServerDownException: The remote procedure call failed.

 at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Utils.GetDSHandle(String domainControllerName, String domainName, IntPtr authIdentity, LoadLibrarySafeHandle libHandle)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.GetDSHandle()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.GetDomainControllerInfo()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.get_SiteName()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroupsHelper()
   at App.AppRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
```

Comment: Seeing that the exception type is `ActiveDirectoryServerDownException`, I'd imagine the application is attempting to contact a domain that doesn't exist (maybe due to a server configuration issue?), or there's something going on with Active Directory.

Comment: this happens for 6-7 requests per day not for all requests

Comment: With that exception and saying it doesn't happen constantly, is the server that hosts the application able to always connect to the domain controllers and not hosted on an unstable connection?